# React JS web App deploy on apache server when check through SEO it says h1 tag does not found

Tags: reactjs, seo

React app deploy on Apache serever working well but when check it for SEO then it gives error i have attached image below[image]

Please help me i have tried SSR but on apache server its not working

even use react- helmet that is also not showing h1 tag or any content when view source in browser

Comment: you have to add json data or String ?

Comment: Can you show how you are creating json? insertOne will add a unique _id property to it if it doesn't already exist, but your json object appears to be a read-only object

Comment: can you post Treatments class ? I think you miss `id` field to add it on a class ?

Comment: here Treatments is array....

Comment: have you add `Id` field in class ?

Comment: then obviously `id` has no coming you have give `id` field in the class.

Comment: but i don't required id to insert

Comment: when you are working with `Array` or 'List' the mongodb generated automatically id field and initialy the `id` is null and when we insert the data it will automatically generate `id` so we have to add it.

Comment: can you show me how to add id in my array

Comment: do one thing in your class add `id` attribute and when you post the data set `id` filed value to `null` .

Comment: still it gives error... Cannot assign to read only property '_id' of {"Diagnosis":"asas","Treatment":[{"id":null,"name":"treatment1","SubTreatment":[{"id":null,"name":"subtreatment1","SubTreatment2":[{"name":"subtreatmentexp1","Name":"asas"}],"Name":"asas"}],"Name":"asas"}]}